# Radio button in ASP.net Core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to learn ASP.net Core (pretty new) and I am trying something like the below scenario.

Having multiple choice options (want to have radio buttons, option to select one for each section)
there can be only one right choice.
When we click submit after selecting one radio button per selection, I need to highlight the correct selections in green and incorrect in red.

I want to have an OnClick which would determine by some name or value which is correct on click and perform this action. I have checked a couple of options but they don't have all these combinations working correctly.

Please suggest the best options using ASP.net Core web application to perform this functionality.

Comment: it can be easily done with jquery, why you are asking for asp.net core while it can be handled at client side

Comment: @saas do you want to do it via Blazor

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, you can use `jquery` to complete.

Since you mentioned how to implement in core, I guess that your data comes from the model in the code behind, right?

So in my example, I use the model to pass the serial number of questions' index, option and correct answer.

Here is my code:

```
public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionNumber { set; get; }
        public IEnumerable<QuestionOption> Options { set; get; }
        public int RightAnswer { set; get; }
    }

    public class QuestionOption
    {
        public int Index { set; get; }
        public string Option { set; get; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Question> questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                 new  Question(){
                  QuestionNumber=1, Options= new List<QuestionOption> {
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=1, Option="A"},
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=2, Option="B"},
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=3, Option="C"},
                  },
                   RightAnswer = 2
                 },
                 new  Question(){
                  QuestionNumber=2, Options= new List<QuestionOption> {
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=1, Option="Kity"},
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=2, Option="Lily"},
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=3, Option="Jack"},
                  },
                   RightAnswer = 1
                 },
                  new  Question(){
                  QuestionNumber=3, Options= new List<QuestionOption> {
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=1, Option="FF"},
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=2, Option="LL"},
                   new QuestionOption(){  Index=3, Option="OO"},
                  },
                   RightAnswer = 3
                 },
            };
            return View(questions);
        }
```

Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication_core_mvc.Models.Question>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts{

    <script>

        function CheckAnswer() {
    var myArray = [];
    @foreach (var d in Model)
    {
        @:myArray.push("@d.QuestionNumber");
    }
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                var right = $("input[type='hidden'][name=" + myArray[i] + "]").val();
                $("input[type='radio'][name=" + myArray[i] + "]").parent().removeClass("right");
                $("input[type='radio'][name=" + myArray[i] + "]").parent().removeClass("wrong");
                $("input[type='radio'][name=" + myArray[i] + "]").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        if ($(this).val() == right) {
                            $(this).parent().addClass("right")
                        } else {
                            $(this).parent().addClass("wrong");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

    }
    </script>

}

<style>
    .right {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .wrong {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>


<p>Select an answer: </p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <label>Question @item.QuestionNumber :</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @foreach (var option in item.Options)
            {
                <input type="radio" value="@option.Index" name="@item.QuestionNumber" /> @option.Option
            }
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.RightAnswer" name="@item.QuestionNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="CheckAnswer()" />
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for. Thank you for the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Give me an example or you could try to refer to my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Display Radio Buttons</h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  
  <div id="question1">
   <p>Please select your gender:</p>
 <div id="answer11">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
 </div>
 <div id="answer12">
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
 </div>
 <div id="answer13">
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
 </div>
  </div>

  <br>  
  
  <div id="question2">
   <p>Please select your age:</p>
   <div id="answer21">
  <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30">
  <label for="age1">0 - 30</label><br>
   </div>
   <div id="answer22">
    <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="60">
    <label for="age2">31 - 60</label><br>  
   </div>
   <div id="answer23">
   <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
   <label for="age3">61 - 100</label><br><br>
   </div>
   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
<script>
 $("form").submit(function(){
  //alert("Submitted");
  $("body div[id^=question] input[type=radio]").each(function(i, e){
   if($(e).is( ":checked" ))
   {
    // Compare $(e).attr('value') vs your result
    if(true) // right answer
     $(e).parent().css( "background-color", "green" );
    else // wrong answer
     $(e).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
   }
  })
  return false;
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the sample code. I will try.